# TO_NUMBER function inside AVG doesn't work

Tags: database, oracle

I'm in trouble with TO_NUMBER ORACLE function.

The query

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(varchar2_column)
FROM TABLE@ANOTHER_DB;
```

works, but if I put `TO_NUMBER` inside `AVG`, ORACLE returns the following error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number ORA-02063: preceding line from ANOTHER_DB Position: 0

The query is the following:

```
SELECT AVG(TO_NUMBER(varchar2_column))
FROM TABLE@ANOTHER_DB;
```

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: The thing is, that there are non numerical data in the remote table. You don't get the error because the normal select statements just fetches some records and not the hole table. The question is, what you want to do with the invalid data...

Comment: Is there a `where` clause in your actual query?  Are you fetching all the data when you run the query with just a `to_number`?  Or only the first few pages of data?  Is `table@another_db` actually a table?  Or a view?  Is there non-numeric data in the column?  If so, how do you want to handle averaging numbers with, say, the string "abc"?  Treat it as NULL?  0?  Something else?

Comment: That error is due to the fact that some of the data in that column cannot be converted to number.

Comment: If you have an actual db release you can try `SELECT AVG(TO_NUMBER(varchar2_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)) FROM TABLE@ANOTHER_DB`

Comment: I read that NULL values are skipped by AVG ...and I know that in the table could be values like '90.0', are this values valid?

Comment: That depends on you nls-settings. Check `SELECT * FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'` if it has the value `.,` it should work. Otherwise `.` will not be interpreted as decimal character.

Comment: Yeah @Radagast81, you're right. The problem is the dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to following query to get a working format mask for your data:

```
SELECT AVG(TO_NUMBER(varchar2_column, 'FM'||REGEXP_REPLACE(varchar2_column,'\d','0'))) 
  FROM TABLE@ANOTHER_DB;
```

That will produce a formatmask replacing all numerical characters with 0, which should work with all your data.

Comment: I did a REPLACE operation (replaced '.' with ','). Do u think it's good?

Comment: I wouldn't do that cause that depends on the NLS-Settings which might differ. When you run your application where `.` is the decimal character that will not work. You can replace it with `SELECT substr(value,1,1) from nls_session_parameters WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'` if you want tho...